# How can i change innerhtml of a div in the parent page from jquery pop up

Tags: jquery, popup, innerhtml

How can i change innerhtml of a div in the aspx page when clicking on jquery pop up close button?

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
$( "#your_dialog" ).bind( "dialogbeforeclose", function(event, ui) {
  $("#main_page_div").html("Your new HTML");
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers